# How to display HTML text in angularjs / bootstrap?

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have angularJS service that returns a string, this string may contain HTML tags, something like this

```
"<strong>Error:</strong>Something is wrong"
```

and I have an element div where I want to put this message

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" ng-bind="vm.message" role="alert"></div>
```

When this message is set to the text above, in HTML page the result shows up AS IS, meaning

```
<strong>Error:</strong>Something is wrong.
```

Instead of

> **Error:**Something is wrong.

How can I output this text like this, so that HTML tags will be rendered?

Comment: `this.message = $sce.trustAsHtml("<strong>Error:</strong>Something is wrong")`. However, your service should probably not return you HTML string like this. Make service return `{type: 'error', message: 'Something is wrong'}` and make proper formatting in template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

use `ng-bind-html` directive to bind string as `html`

Comment: can i know why -1 for this answer ?

Comment: I actually consider it as an answer. The only thing he forgot to mention is that for ng-bind-html to work, I have to include angular-sanitize.min.js file and add ngSanitize to my app module: var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);

Comment: @ShudhanshShekhar: Referral links are encouraged in stackoverflow please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.